# How to round number down to nearest multiple of 7?

Tags: formula

I'm trying to find Salesforce's equivalent to Excel's **=FLOOR(number,significance)**, and more specifically, I'm looking to round down a number to the nearest multiple of 7. For example, if number=303, the result should be 301.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a minimum and maximum value for the number field?

Comment: Minimum 0 and no max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Math.mod(number, significance)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_math.htm#apex_System_Math_mod) you could get the reminder, which can be subtracted from the original value to get the nearest multiple:

```java
Integer result = nearestMinimumMultiple(303, 7);
Assert.areEqual(301, result);

result = nearestMinimumMultiple(24, 2);
Assert.areEqual(24, result);

result = nearestMinimumMultiple(128, 5);
Assert.areEqual(125, result);

Decimal value = 125.3;
Long res = nearestMinimumMultiple(value, 11L);
Assert.areEqual(121L, res);

public static Integer nearestMinimumMultiple(Integer value, Integer base) {
    return value - Math.Mod(value, base);
}

public static Long nearestMinimumMultiple(Decimal value, Long base) {
    Long val = Math.floor(value).longValue();
    return val - Math.Mod(val, base);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a formula field: `Field__c - MOD(Field__c, 7)`